# How do I use the Time class on hash values?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am working through Chris Pine's Ruby book, and I am slightly confused why my code doesn't quite work.

I have a file called `birthdays.txt` which has around 10 lines of text which resembles:

```
Andy Rogers, 1987, 02, 03
```

etc.

My code as follows:

```
hash = {}

File.open('birthdays.txt', "r+").each_line do |line|
  name, date = line.chomp.split( /, */, 2 )
  hash[name] = date
end

puts 'whose birthday would you like to know?'

name = gets.chomp
puts hash[name]                                    
puts Time.local(hash[name])
```

My question is, why does the last line of code, `Time.local(hash[name])` produce this output?:

```
1987-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

instead of:

```
1987-02-03 00:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line = "Andy Rogers, 1987, 02, 03\n"
name, date = line.chomp.split( /, */, 2 ) #split (', ', 2) is less complex.
#(Skipping the hash stuff; it's fine)
p date #=>          "1987, 02, 03"
# Time class can't handle one string, it wants: "1987", "02", "03"
# so: 
year, month, day = date.split(', ')
p Time.local(year, month, day)
# or do it all at once (google "ruby splat operator"):
p Time.local(*date.split(', '))
```

Comment: thanks for the speedy responses guys! both very helpful. I was wondering, as i have to find 'line' from a text file, how can i do it without using the; File.open('birthdays.txt', "r+").each_line do |line| bit of code, which results in the local variable date being unavailable?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for [Time.local](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-local),

Time.local doesn't parse a string. It expects you to pass a separate parameter for year, month, and date. When you pass a string like "1987, 02, 03", it takes that to be a single parameter, the year. It then tries to coerce that string into an integer - in this case, 1982.

so, basically, you want to slice up that string into the year, month, and day. there's multiple ways to do this. Here's one (it can be made shorter, but this is the most clear way)

```
year, month, date = date.split(/, */).map {|x| x.to_i}
Time.local(year, month, date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {}


File.open('birthdays.txt').each_line do |line|
  line = line.chomp
  name, date = line.split(',',2)
  year, month, day = date.split(/, */).map {|x| x.to_i}
  hash[name] = Time.local(year, month, day)
end

puts 'Whose birthday and age do you want to find out?'
name = gets.chomp

    if hash[name] == nil
       puts ' Ummmmmmmm, dont know that one'
    else
       age_secs = Time.new - hash[name]
       age_in_years = (age_secs/60/60/24/365 + 1)

  t = hash[name]
  t.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
  puts "#{name}, will be, #{age_in_years.to_i} on #{t.strftime("%m/%d/")}"
end
```

had to move the Time.local call earlier in the program and then bingo, cheers guys!